# CSS, nth-child doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I am building a form, but for a crazy reason, nth-child doesn't work on input fields, as it seems. A jsfiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/nGuLp/. The second input field shouldn't get a margin-right, but it does. Why doesn't this work?
HTML:

```
<div class="block-inner">
<h1>Blah</h1>
<hr />
<input type="text" placeholder="Voornaam" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="left" />
<input type="text" placeholder="Achternaam" name="surname" id="surname" class="left"    />

</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
width: 45%;
margin-right: 10%;
}

input:nth-child(2){
margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `:nth-of-type(n)`, otherwise the counter increments for each element within `.block-inner` so the two inputs results in 3rd and 4th position.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, this is css2 and is supported by all browsers.

```
div input + input{ }
```

Will select the second input.

You second child will select the input if the input was the second child. The second child in the div is the hr.

Comment: `input + input` selects the second `<input>`, so it works in the OPs example, but it's not a generic solution. Use `input:nth-of-type(2)` instead - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:nth-of-type

Comment: @RobW: it’s only not generic if the OP is looking for every second `input` to have no right margin. (Which may well be true, but I can’t tell from the question.) If the OP actually just wants the second `input` to have no right margin, then Niels’ code is correct, and `nth-child` would be the wrong choice.

Comment: You don't need the div here. And `elt + elt` selects any `elt` that is a direct sibling of another one: it could select the third, fourth one if they existed.

Answer (score 0):

The `nth-child` selector doesn't single out the elements of the same type. Your first input element is the third child of its parent.